# Libraries for Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, reusability

Where can I get list of libraries/resources which help for incorporating Material Design in pre-lollipop devices? A link for a single library you are familiar with could help. I am familiar with the following

- https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton
- https://github.com/keithellis/MaterialWidget
- https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary
- http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html and
- AppCompat v21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take look at https://android-arsenal.com/. It's much easier to find something there.

Here's mine:
https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon. The good thing about the library is that is supports realtime, animated shadows and ripples (soon there will be borderless mode as well) back to Android 2.1. The bad thing is that it's still under development, so there are some things missing.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

@makata

Just try to change with Android Studio, you can get Material Design easily.
Here is the android official design library.
You need a single line of codes to add to your build.gradle as a dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Here is the [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for the material design library.

Here is the sample [blogpost](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en) from a GDE (Thailand)